# Pandas column of nanosecond resolution Timestamps change when writing a new timestamp value for one row. Is this a bug?

Tags: pandas

The code in question

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2020-06-18 09:18:00'),
                                             periods=3,
                                             freq='10ns')})

print(df)
df.loc[1, 'datetime'] = pd.Timestamp('2020-06-18 09:18:00.000000015')
print(df)
```

The dataframe datetime column looses the nanosecond timestamp values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the dataframe corresponding to your test, you can do:

```py
df[df.datetime == pd.Timestamp('2020-06-18 09:18:00')]
```

This way you keep your column instead of having True/False values.
If this is not the answer you're looking for, please give us more details.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, that last line just is there to show that all the timestamps have changed to the same value.  I removed it from the question to make the problem clearer

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that this is a bug in Pandas 0.25.3.
It works as expected in Pandas 1.0.4.